# How to upload multiple file in django admin models

Tags: python, django

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to=settings.FILE_PATH)
```

For uploading a file in django models I used the above line. But For uploading multiple file through django admin model what should I do? I found [this](http://scompt.com/blog/archives/2007/11/03/multiple-file-uploads-in-django)  But this is for forms. Can  I use this for models?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have multiple files for the same field you would have to write your own field and widget based on the form field you have found otherwise have a separate model for file with a foreign key to your main model and use ModelInline.

models.py

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class PageFile(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.FILE_PATH)
    page = models.ForeignKey('Page')
```

admin.py

```
 class PageFileInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = PageFile

 class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        inlines = [PageFileInline,]
```

Comment: Field 'file' doesn't have a default value. This is the error I am getting.

Comment: file = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.FILE_PATH, blank=True, null=True)
or post complete traceback

Comment: i added the traceback in question.